# Captcha not showing odd characters like �

Tags: magento, captcha, symbols

Using magento I installed Magestore's Product Questions on my localhost and all working great. I uploaded it to live website and now doesnt work. The captcha doesnt show (http://camerakings.co.uk/lanparte-professional-kit-v2-with-7-hdmi-monitor-save-800#product-tabs-container), and when you click the link that shows the captcha (http://camerakings.co.uk/productcontact/index/imagecaptcha/) it just shows loads of these symbols � and numbers.

I spoke with magestore and they said they didnt know (where not actually very helpful at all even though provided ftp and have a lot of their plugins). I appreciate this is a plugin and I would have to paste in all the code for people to check this properly, but just wondered if people had ever experienced it with Captcha before? Or if they know why these � appear so I could investigate further.

I have tried reinstalling the plugin but no success.

Answer (score 0):

The correct `Content-Type` header is not being sent with the response.

It is coming back as `text/html` which causes the browser not to render it as an image.

You may need to edit the plugin or Magento routes to add:

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
```

to that response.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how to guide you in doing that since it is a captcha plugin which should do that for you and I'm not too familiar with Magento's internals.

[image: wrong content type]

Comment: Thanks! I have tried this in what I think generates the captcha but it doesnt seem to work, but I will put this within some of the other files and update

Comment: I have checked and the file that generates the captcha outputs at jpeg. You can see the full text here -> https://jsfiddle.net/4ewcqcxp/ -> it says header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); -> any idea?

Comment: Perhaps it does, but based on the response I'm getting from the actual page, it is not returning the right content type.  See screnshot in updated answer.  Also, the image is a png according to the output.